# GuzzlePHP mock response content

Tags: php, guzzle

I want to mock a response to the Guzzle request:

```
 $response = new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar']);

 //how do I set content of $response to--> "some mocked content"

 $client = Mockery::mock('GuzzleHttp\Client');
 $client->shouldReceive('get')->once()->andReturn($response);
```

I noticed I need to add as third parameter the interface:

```
 GuzzleHttp\Stream\StreamInterface
```

but there are so many implementations of it, and I want to return a simple string. Any ideas?

Edit: now I use this:

```
 $response = new Response(200, [], GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream::factory('bad xml here'));
```

but when I check this:

```
$response->getBody()->getContents()
```

I get an empty string. Why is this?

Edit 2: this happened to me only when I used xdebug, when it runs normally it works great!

Comment: Why not just mock the `Response` as well?! I suppose that the behaviour of the class under test depends on the response. So you'd want to mock it too, so you'd be sure that each time the input data for your CUT is the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The previous answer is for Guzzle 3. Guzzle 5 uses the following:

```
<?php
$body = GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream::factory('some mocked content');
$response = new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'], $body);
```

Comment: I added some of the code to my post, can you please look at it?

Comment: \GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream::factory (backslash or use **use** statement)

Answer (score 33):

We'll just keep doing this. The previous answer is for Guzzle 5, this is for Guzzle 6:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;

$stream = Psr7\stream_for('{"data" : "test"}');
$response = new Response(200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'], $stream);
```

Comment: Looking at the [Guzzle source](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/1.2.1/src/Response.php#L96), Response does this for you automatically. Just pass a string.

Answer (score 7):

Using @tomvo answer and the comment from @Tim - this is what I did for testing Guzzle 6 inside my Laravel app:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;

$string = json_encode(['data' => 'test']);
$response = new Response(200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'], $string);

$guzzle = Mockery::mock(GuzzleHttp\Client::class);
$guzzle->shouldReceive('get')->once()->andReturn($response);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Guzzle\Http\Message\Response`](http://api.guzzlephp.org/class-Guzzle.Http.Message.Response.html) allows you to specify the third parameter as a string.

```
$body = '<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>';
$response = new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'], $body);
```

If you'd prefer a solution that implements `Guzzle\Stream\StreamInterface`, then I recommend using [`Guzzle\Http\EntityBody`](http://api.guzzlephp.org/class-Guzzle.Http.EntityBody.html) for the most straightforward implementation:

```
$body = Guzzle\Http\EntityBody::fromString('<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>');
$response = new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'], $body);
```

Answer (score 3):

For Guzzle 7, you can use the `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::streamFor()` method as follows:

```
$data = json_encode(['X-Foo' => 'Bar']);
$stream = Utils::streamFor($data);
```

And then you can pass the `$stream` object to the `andReturn` method of the  mocked client.