# How do I replace a method in a mocked class

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I am trying to convert some integration tests into unit tests:  The original test code partially worked, but hadn't been run in a long time and the code under test is legacy-but-mostly-working.  The test code also made assumptions about the DB and external resources that are not valid in a unit-test environment.  Because current test coverage is poor, I'm trying to minimize my edits to the existing code while adding unit tests to verify how I think it's supposed to operate.  I appreciate that the code under test might not be following best practices, but *if* *possible* would like to have working unit tests before I modify working code.

I want to use mocks to replace the external calls, but am having trouble doing that in PHPUnit.  I've seen references to other frameworks like Mockery and Prophecy, but all current tests are written in PHPUnit, so I'd prefer to stick with it. The examples I've found so far either don't work, or don't show the code under test, or seem to make silent assumptions that don't quite hold. In particular:

- The code under test makes heavy use of the built-in `resolve()` function to do dependency injection, and I haven't found any documentation on it at all - and certainly not in the context of mocking unit tests.
- Although I have found several examples that talk about replacing the *return* *value* from a method, I haven't found any that let me override the operation of the method.
- The PHP version is 8.1.16 and my ORM is Laravel Framework 8.83.27, although this question doesn't deal directly with DB access.

I'll start with my draft of the TestCase, then show the code under test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Services\Implementations\SarahHandler;
use App\Services\Implementations\SarahRequest;

use Tests\TestCase;

class SarahCodeToExamineMocksTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testChainHandling()
    {
        $mockRequest = $this->getMockBuilder(SarahRequest::class)
            ->setMethods(['sendRequest'])
            ->getMock();

        $mockRequest->expects($this->once()) // assert mock's only be called once
            ->method('sendRequest')
            ->will({
                $mockRequest->response = 'Mock Request Response';
                return $mockRequest;
            });

        $url = 'https://stackoverflow.com';

        // Original source code uses this resolve() built-in.
        $handler = resolve(SarahHandler::class);
        $result = $handler->handle($url);

        // Assert it completed using the Mock
        assertEquals($result, 'Mock Request Response');
    }
}
```

The class to be mocked is more complex than this, but this shows the essential pieces.  I would like to keep as much of the class in place as possible and only mock the external call ( `sendRequest()` method) itself:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Implementations;

use App\Services\Interfaces\SarahRequestInterface;

class SarahRequest implements SarahRequestInterface
{
    private $url;
    private $response;

    public function setUrl(string $url): SarahRequestInterface
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        return $this;
    }

    public function sendRequest(): SarahRequestInterface
    {
        echo 'Calling the internet...';
        $this->response = 'Real external string';
        return $this;
    }

    public function getResponse(): string
    {
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

This is the class which provides the top-level function-under test.  Again, the real version does more than this, and I want to cover as much of that functionality as I can, but this shows the instantiation of the to-be-mocked class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Implementations;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

use App\Services\Interfaces\SarahRequestInterface;

class SarahHandler
{
    public function handle(string $url)
    {
        return $this->doStuff($url);
    }

    private function doStuff(string $url): string
    {
        $request = resolve(SarahRequestInterface::class);
        $response = $request->getResponse($url);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Here's the interface which is being used to index the class which needs a good mocking:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Interfaces;

interface SarahRequestInterface
{
    public function setUrl(string $url): SarahRequestInterface;
    public function sendRequest(): SarahRequestInterface;
    public function getResponse(): string;
}
```

Here's the actual syntax error I get with the code as it appears above:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ParseError: syntax error, unexpected token "{" in /app/tests/Unit/SarahCodeToExamineMocksTest.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php(49): PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::load()
#1 /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(397): PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::checkAndLoad()
#2 /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(536): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFile()
#3 /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestSuiteMapper.php(67): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFiles()
#4 /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(391): PHPUnit\TextUI\TestSuiteMapper->map()
#5 /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(112): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->handleArguments()
#6 /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(97): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run()
#7 /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(98): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#8 {main}

Next PHPUnit\TextUI\RuntimeException: syntax error, unexpected token "{" in /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:99
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(98): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php on line 99
```

Finally, some references

- [This SO Q&A talks about mocking hard-coded dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561702/how-to-unit-test-a-method-with-dependencies-in-php), but those examples of "hard-coded" dependencies use a different instantiation from the `resolve()` I'm seeing, and some of the functions seem to have been deprecated in the decade since it was posted.
- [This blog post](https://ericdraken.com/phpunit-mock-hard-dependencies-aliases/) is more recent, but also skips `resolve()`, and following the procedure as best I could seemed to disable the ORM.
- [These docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking) seemed to not cover the case of needing to replace *functionality* (the assignment to `SarahRequest->response`), *or* the `resolve()` function. Similarly with the other examples I've found.

Are there ways to do these mocks? To what extent do I need to refactor the code under test and what's the recommended way of doing that?

Comment: Based on the laravel docs, it looks like the resolve method has to do [with their service container](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-resolve)

Based on reading about their service container, it looks like they provide the ability to [bind implementations based on an interface.](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations)

So I assume what you would want to do is, bind a mock implementation of `SarahRequestInterface` prior to calling resolve, to ensure that resolve returns the mock instance with an overridden sendRequest method.

Comment: @MatthewAnderson Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm trying it out, but getting other errors; probably related to my novice-level PHP hacks. I'll update when I have more info.

Comment: @MatthewAnderson You got me unblocked on this; I had to fix a couple other issues as well, so will be posting my own answer with the full details... but I would like to accept and upvote an answer from you if you want to post your comment or similar as an answer.

Comment: Related post about "monkey-patching" in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137006/redefine-class-methods-or-class

Comment: Depending on what needs to be replaced in the Mock, it may be sufficient to inject a response from an external system, as described in [this article](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html) and [this SO Q & As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506568/guzzlephp-mock-response-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MatthewAnderson's comment on my Q got me looking at ServiceProviders and trying to subclass the code under test, which was a key step in solving this. I had to fix a couple other issues to get a fully-working group of files, so am posting them here for comparison:

The TestCase calls `$this->app->bind()` to select a mocked subclass of the code containing the method I want to swap out:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Services\Implementations\SarahHandler;
use App\Services\Implementations\SarahRequest;
use App\Services\Interfaces\SarahRequestInterface;

use Tests\Mocks\MockSarahRequest;
use Tests\TestCase;

class SarahCodeToExamineMocksTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testChainHandling()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            SarahRequestInterface::class,
            MockSarahRequest::class
        );

        $url = 'https://stackoverflow.com';

        // Original source code uses this resolve() built-in.
        $handler = resolve(SarahHandler::class);
        $result = $handler->handle($url);

        // Assert it completed using the Mock
        $this->assertEquals($result, 'Mock Request Response');
    }
}
```

The variables in the class being mocked needed to be `protected` rather than `private` so that my (Mock) subclass could use them:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Implementations;

use App\Services\Interfaces\SarahRequestInterface;

class SarahRequest implements SarahRequestInterface
{
    protected string $url;
    protected string $response;

    public function setUrl(string $url): SarahRequestInterface
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        return $this;
    }

    public function sendRequest(): SarahRequestInterface
    {
        echo 'Calling the internet...';
        $this->response = 'Real external string';
        return $this;
    }

    public function getResponse(): string
    {
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

I was skipping a couple steps in the top-level code under tests.  These were in the original code, but I missed them when constructing my example for post:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Implementations;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

use App\Services\Interfaces\SarahRequestInterface;

class SarahHandler
{
    public function handle(string $url)
    {
        return $this->doStuff($url);
    }

    private function doStuff(string $url): string
    {
        $request = resolve(SarahRequestInterface::class);
        $response = $request->setUrl($url)->sendRequest()->getResponse();
        return $response;
    }
}
```

And here's the mock class I wrote to replace the target code during the test:

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Mocks;

use App\Services\Implementations\SarahRequest;
use App\Services\Interfaces\SarahRequestInterface;

class MockSarahRequest extends SarahRequest
{
    public function sendRequest(): SarahRequestInterface
    {
        echo 'No calls allowed';
        $this->response = 'Mock Request Response';
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error. In your SarahCodeToExamineMocksTest.php class the following line is repeated twice. Remove that.

```
public function testChainHandling()
{
```

Comment: fixed cut & paste error.

Comment: The code which generated the above-quoted error didn't have the duplicated line which you pointed out. Counting lines down, the `{` which generates the error comes from the `will()` call in setting up the mock.